# Ignore failed validation for one object in Rails's mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm working on Rails 4 project, in which I need to update one user's "attendances" (has_many) via mass assignment. Quite easy:

```
@user.update(user_params)
(...)
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :attendances_attributes => [:id, :event_id])
end
```

Now, the problem is that I've got a validation in Attendance model, which ensures uniqueness of user_id within the scope of event_id (ensures no pair of user and event is ever repeated). That's fine, the problem comes when one user wants to create let's say 4 attendances, two of which are invalid for this reason. Then Rails stops the whole thing and none of them gets inserted.

What i'd like to achieve is to get the valid two inserted.

I know I should pass the attendance id of existing record, so they only get updated, but this comes from a mobile platform and it gets quite difficult, since it's the first screen of the app (no data yet).

I guess one solution would be forgetting about strong_parameters and mass assignment and creating the records one by one from the params, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better solution! Maybe in the validation statement through a reject_if?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to "save_valid_and_not_invalid". You'll have to handle this case in the controller, e.g.:

```
if @user.update params
  render "success"
else
  @user.attendances.select!(&:valid?)
  if @user.save
    render "success, except the invalid attendances that we didn't save"
  else
    render "error"
  end
end
```